# discord.py kick command thats sends a dm to user that is kicked

Tags: python, discord, bots

I am trying to make a discord.py bot with a kick command. So when you do `;kick (member)` it will kick the mentioned user and send that user a dm telling them they are kicked from the server. However it only dms the user if the dm is a normal message and not embed. I'm still pretty new to python so I don't understand whats wrong with the code. Here is my code:

````
    @commands.guild_only()
    @has_permissions(kick_members = True)
    async def kick(self, ctx, member : discord.Member=None, *, reason="No reason was provided"):
      aA=ctx.author.avatar_url
      desc1=f"You are missing the following argument(s): `Member`\n```{prefix}kick <member> [reason]```"
      embed1=discord.Embed(title="Missing Argument",description=desc1,color=rC)
      embed1.set_author(name="Error",icon_url=aA)
      try:
        if member == None:
          await ctx.send(embed=embed1)
          return
        if member == ctx.author:
          await ctx.send(f"You can't kick yourself.")
          return
        try:
          em1=discord.Embed(description=f"You were kicked out from **{ctx.guild.name}**\nReason: `{reason}`.",color=rC)
          em1.set_author(icon_url=aA)
          await member.send(embed=em1)
        except:
          pass
        em2=discord.Embed(description=f"{tick} {member.mention} has been kicked out of **{ctx.guild.name}**. Reason: `{reason}`",color=gC)
        await member.kick(reason = reason)
        await ctx.send(embed=em2)
      except:
        await ctx.send("An unknown error occured.)
````

There isn't any errors sent in the console when I run the bot or use the command

Answer (score 1):

you can use:
`await member.send(embed=em2)`
ctx will send in the channel where the command was done.